# HttpClient.SendAsync sits and never progress, even though the data sent is processed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.6

I am having to rewrite an application from `ASP.Net Core` to `ASP.Net 4.6.1` and in the core version of the application I am sending `Json` data to BugZilla for processing and it works fine. It sends the data and gets the response back fairly quickly. That same code in the 4.6.1 version of the application sits and hangs on the send command. I can go into BugZilla and see that it got the data and generated the bug but even after 15 minutes the application does not progress. I am brand new to Task and sending data via Json so I am not sure why I am running into this problem. No errors are ever returned and in debug mode I can step through everything and know that it is handing and waiting at the `SendAsync` line. What am I doing wrong that breaks this in 4.6.1?

```
private static async Task<int> LogToBugZilla(string Component, Exception ex)
{
    var ErrorSummary = "Auto Error Logging: " + ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException.Message;

    var BugData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Bugzilla_api_key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BugZillaAPIKey"] },
        { "product", "Job Site" },
        { "component", Component },
        { "version", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppVersion"] },
        { "summary", ErrorSummary },
        { "op_sys", "All" },
        { "platform", "Other" },
        { "description", ex.StackTrace + ex.InnerException.StackTrace }
    };

    string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BugData, Formatting.None);
    var Client = new HttpClient();
    var Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://bugzilla/rest/bug");
    Request.Content = new StringContent(Json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    Request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    var Response = await Client.SendAsync(Request);
    var JsonResults = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var Results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(JsonResults);
        return Results["id"];
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
public static string ProcessError(Exception ex, string OriginatingController)
{
    var Component = GetComponent(OriginatingController);
    string UserErrorMessage = "";

    switch (ex.GetType().ToString())
    {
        case "System.Data.DataException":
            LogToITSupport("Database Connection");
            UserErrorMessage = @"An error has accrued connecting to the database. <a href=""mailto:"">IT Support</a> has been notified  of this error. Please try your request again later, thank you.";
            break;

        default:
            var BugID = LogToBugZilla(Component, ex).Result;
            UserErrorMessage = @"An error has accrued processing your request and a log of this error has been made on the <a href=""http://bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=" + BugID + "\">Internal Tools BugZilla system</a> with an ID of " + BugID + ". Please try your request again later, thank you.";
            break;
    }

    return UserErrorMessage;
}
```

And to just restate, the application hangs on the code `var Response = await Client.SendAsync(Request);`

Edit 2:

Contrller Code:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new JobSightDbContext())
        {
            var model = db.ReleaseVersions
                            .OrderByDescending(rv => rv.DateReleased)
                            .Select(rv => new ReleaseNotesVM()
                            {
                                ID = rv.ID,
                                CurrentVersion = string.Concat(rv.Major, ".", rv.Minor, ".", rv.Patch),
                                CurrentVersionReleaseDate = rv.DateReleased,
                                ReleaseNotes = rv.ReleaseNotes.Select(rn => rn.Note).ToList()
                            }).First();

            //model.VersionList = db.ReleaseVersions
            //                      .OrderByDescending(rv => rv.DateReleased)
            //                      .Select(rv => new SelectListItem()
            //                      {
            //                          Value = rv.ID.ToString(),
            //                          Text = string.Concat(rv.Major, '.', rv.Minor, '.', rv.Patch)
            //                      }).ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Data.DataException ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = EHALM.ProcessError(ex, RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString());
        return View("Dashboard");
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking `LogToBugZilla`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I catch an error inside an action/class, parse the error type and invoke based off error type passing the data in. I can follow the program via debugger from the catch all the way to the `SendAsync` line and everything works but once it hits that line the application just sits there.

Comment: It would be helpful to see that code. Most likely you aren't doing the await there properly. Is catch/invoke being done in a web app or desktop app?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: Code further up your call stack is almost certainly calling `Wait()` or `Result`, which can [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain on my blog.

Comment: Are you calling `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait` anywhere in the call chain?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment added the calling code

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete yep, your `LogToBugZilla(Component, ex).Result` is causing the lockup. Go read Stephen Cleary's blog post. This has nothing specificly to do with `HttpClient`, you can cause the same lockup with `private static async Task<int> LogToBugZilla(string Component, Exception ex) { await Task.Delay(1000); return 0;)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to go on a limp here and say that you use `LogToBugZilla` like this higher up in your call stack:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    var result = LogToBugZilla("Component", exception).Result;
}
```

This is effectively deadlocking your code and is the reason why [you shouldn't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). You need to make your code "async all the way", up onto the top of your call-stack. This means turning `DoStuff` to `DoStuffAsync` and calling it like this:

```
public async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
    var result = await LogToBugZillaAsync("Component", exception);
    // Do stuff with result
}
```

Note I added the "async" postfix to `LogToBugZilla`, as per the recommended coding convention.

**Edit:**

Given you provided the calling method, it should look like this:

```
public static async Task<string> ProcessErrorAsync(
            Exception ex, string OriginatingController)
{
    var Component = GetComponent(OriginatingController);
    string UserErrorMessage = "";

    switch (ex.GetType().ToString())
    {
        case "System.Data.DataException":
            LogToITSupport("Database Connection");
            UserErrorMessage = @"An error has accrued connecting to the 
            database. <a href=""mailto:"">IT Support</a> has been notified
            of this error. Please try your request again later, thank you.";
            break;

        default:
            var bugId = await LogToBugZillaAsync(Component, ex);
            UserErrorMessage = @"An error has accrued processing your request 
            and a log of this error has been made 
            on the <a href=""http://bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=" + BugID +
            "\">Internal Tools BugZilla system</a> 
            with an ID of " + bugId + ". Please try your request again later, thank you.";
            break;
    }
    return UserErrorMessage;
}
```

Now remember this needs to go all the way up. This means that every method calling `ProcessErrorAsync`, in itself should be made `async` and return either a `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Comment: I added the controller code for the top caller. Since it is an ActionResult the only option I know is to change it to a `IAsyncReult` to do the "go all the way up" but then I can't just return a view. So in this case do I need to just add `.ConfigureAwait(false);` to my call?

Comment: No, you can use a `Task<ActionResult>` and `await` the call inside the controller action.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some generic code I use to send HTTP requests. Works fine only diff is I am using .Net 4.5. Should not be a problem for 4.6

```
private async Task<HttpUtilResponse> DoRequest(List<RequestResponseHeader> headers, HttpMethod method, string url, string requestData) {
     HttpUtilResponse response = new HttpUtilResponse();
     string responseData = string.Empty;
     using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()) {          
        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url)) {
           if (headers != null) {
              headers.ForEach(h => request.Headers.Add(h.Name, h.Value));
           }               
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestData)) {
              if (AppConfig.LogRequestContent) {
                 LOG.Debug(requestData);
              }
              request.Content = new StringContent(requestData, Encoding.UTF8, JSON_CONTENT);                  
           }
           using (HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.SendAsync(request, CancelToken.Token)) {
              response.StatusCode = msg.StatusCode;
              response.ReasonPhrase = msg.ReasonPhrase;
              using (HttpContent content = msg.Content) {
                 response.ResponseText = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              }
           }
        }
     }
     return response;
  }
```

Comment: I am betting the OP's problem is he is deadlocking his code due to syncronously calling `.Result` on `DoRequest`, your fix won't really help (unless maybe if you added `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to every `await` call)